# In R, why does adding 0 to a slice index change the length of the result?

Tags: r, slice, indices

In R, when I add `0` (or a variable that has a value of `0`) to each index of a slice, I end up with a result that is one element longer than I expect.
Why is this, and how can I achieve the `1 2 3 4 5` result I expect?

```
my_vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

my_vec[1 : 5] 
my_vec[1 + 0 : 5 + 0]
```

returns

```
1 2 3 4 5     # my_vec[1 : 5]
1 2 3 4 5 6   # my_vec[1+0 : 5+0]
```

Comment: this is a order of operations issue. try `my_vec[(1+0):(5+0)]`

Comment: I'd just add that `:` should not be considered as slice, it's a sequence operator. Might not sound like it matters, but it returns a vector, so `1 + 0 : 5 + 0` evaluates pretty much the same as `1 + seq(0,5)` . And when coming from Python, this can bite quite hard ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using parentheses so that the addition operation is executed first:

```
my_vec[(1+0):(5+0)]
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```